# Zend Framework 2 form radiobutton rendering exception

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I have the following problem.

I have a ZF2 (Version 2.5.1) form including this:

```
// Gender
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'gender',
    'type' => 'radio',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Gender',
        'value_options' => array(
            '1' => 'Male',
            '2' => 'Female'
        )
    )
));
```

And attempting to render it in a view like this:

```
echo "<div>";
echo $this->formLabel($form->get('gender')) . "\n";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('gender'));
echo "</div>";
```

Which gives me the following exception (thrown via the call to formRow):

```
Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormMultiCheckbox::render requires that the element is of type Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox
```

With the exception being thrown at line #103 in the file zend-form\src\View\Helper\FormMultiCheckbox.php.

Is there anyone else that have had this problem? Am I doing something horribly wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which of the 2 render statements is throwing the error? (`formLabel` or `formRow`) From what I see though, should all be correct. What class is the form class extending? And how have you created the associated InputFilter?

Comment: It is the call to formRow that throws. The form class extends Zend\Form\Form. I have created an InputFilter for the form, but currently it is not attached to the form object, hence it shouldn't have any influence, right?

Comment: Can you show us the type of the gender radio: `$form->get('gender')` as in a `var_dump($var)` before the `formRow($element)`. The Radio button class is an instance of the MultiCheckbox due to extending it, so I'm curious what is passed along to the form viewhelper of the `FormMultiCheckbox`.

Comment: var_dump($form->get('gender') gives this (labels and values are in Norwegian), first 500 chars:
`code`
object(Zend\Form\Element\Radio)#246 (13) {
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "radio"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "gender"
  }
  ["disableInArrayValidator":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["useHiddenElement":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["uncheckedValue":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["valueOptions":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Mann"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "Kvinne"
  }

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing differently now, but it seems to be working. Sorry for the bother, thanks for the help!